# How to use string repeat in c++?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, repeat

I came across this code recently.
can someone explain it please.

```
string generateTheString(int n) {
    return "b" + string(n - 1, 'a' + n % 2);
}
```

What does `string(n - 1, 'a' + n % 2)` mean here?

Comment: see the constructors for a string [her](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/)

Answer (score 0):

```
string(n - 1, 'a' + n % 2);
```

Is calling the [string constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) (specifically #2).

Your string will be instantiated with `n - 1` instances of the character `'a' + n % 2`.

That's then concatenated with `"b"`.

For example, if `n` is 5, you'll get `n - 1 => 4` of `'a' + 5 % 2 => 'a' + 1 => 'b'` and then prepend another `b`. So you'll wind up with `"bbbbb"`.

Comment: However, the C++ standard does not require that `'a' + 1` is `'b'`. It's true for every character encoding I know of, but folks who write this sort of code need to consider that it might not be portable.